# What does clip=True mean in mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_sphere()

Tags: python, scripting

This argument seems to be undocumented.
Does it mean that if an intersection point is not between the line's two endpoints (line_a and line_b) then it is not returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Yes, it does.

---

**Long Answer**:

The source code is located in [this file](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/source/blender/python/mathutils/mathutils_geometry.c#l615). It calls [`line_point_factor_v3`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/source/blender/blenlib/intern/math_geom.c#l1985) which subtracts both, the end point `line_b` and the intersection point `isect` from the start point `line_a`, to get the relative vectors from `line_a` to `line_b` and the intersection point `isect`, respectively.

It then divides the dot product of these relative vectors by the squared length from `line_a` to `line_b`.

Since both relative vectors are on the same line, the result of the dot product is negative if they point in opposite directions, else the result of the dot product is the product of the lengths of these vectors.

So basically its

```
dist(line_a, line_b) * dist(line_a, isect) / dist(line_a, line_b)²
```

If clip is `True` it checks wether this is between `0.0` and `1.0` which means the intersection point is on the line segment from `line_a` to `line_b`